# Why are two Odoo instances installed and how they work?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I installed Odoo v10 in my system a few months ago. Yesterday, while i was working, Odoo running on my localhost crashed due to some faulty code. **I opened it through localhost,it gave `Internal server error` but when I opened it through my system's IP address, it was running correctly**.

At this time

> Why was one instance working while other one was crashed?

So, i wanted to ask, how are these two instances of Odoo installed on my system and how they work because after running Odoo through IP address(since my localhost:8069 was crashed) I made some changes in python code(also restarted the service) but they didn't reflected on that Odoo instance (`my_IP_addr:8069`) but were working on `localhost:8069`

> Why changes reflected to only localhost:8069 but not on my_IP_addr:8069?

Answer (score 0):

1. > Why was one instance working while other one was crashed?

   - Have you already restart your instance? i mean, when you change your python files and not restarting the odoo-services in your instances, **it will not changes the module** and when you copy your addons and placed in localhost, you start the localhost, it will change the module based on latest modification in your localhost. Because you start the localhost after you place the latest modif addons.
2. > Why changes reflected to only localhost:8069 but not on
   >   my_IP_addr:8069?

   - This should not happen if you do it right

Restarting the service for upgrading the python code, and Click upgrade button in Apps>youraddonsname for upgrading the XML.

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, i did it correctly. After i crashed my localhost, i open it through my IP address and it wasn't crashed. If my server has crashed, it has to be for all instances(localhost and my IP address one). It was strange to see one instance running while other is crashed. That's why i asked it, hopping for someone to answer the reason.